# Mooc.fi Exercise: Average of positive numbers fail

Tags: java

I've spent all day but couldn't find a solution. Could someone please help and tell me what the error is? 75% of the code is correct, mooc says. But it fails because:

Fail: When input was: 0, output shouldn't contain: 0.

In other words, when I input 0 alone, it calculates the average of that one 0. However, the exercise calls for all non-positive numbers to be excluded from the average calculation.

This contradictory output is what I get when I enter a zero:

Give a number:
0
Cannot calculate the average
Average of the numbers: 0.0

Here is my code. I'm a beginner in Java and perhaps you guys can see something I can't. All help much appreciated

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AverageOfPositiveNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numberofinputs = 0;
        double sumofinputs = 0;
        double average = 0;
        double negative = 0;
        double positive = 0;
  

// For repeatedly asking for numbers
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Give a number: ");
    // For reading user input
            int numberFromUser = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());           
          
            if (numberFromUser <= 0) {
                negative = numberFromUser;
            } else {
                positive = numberFromUser;
            }            
            
            if (positive == 0){
            
                System.out.println("Cannot calculate the average");              
            } 
            
            if (numberFromUser == 0){             
             
                break;
            }
   
            if (positive == numberFromUser){
                numberofinputs = numberofinputs + 1;
                sumofinputs = (sumofinputs + positive);
                average = (double) sumofinputs/numberofinputs;
            }       
        }   
            
        System.out.println("Average of the numbers: " + average);       
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Dump everything between the read and the last "if" but  keep the break  if. change the last if to (numberFromUser > 0)   { make average}  .  Note the average of 0,0,0 is 0.  if you don't give it some positive numbers the average is 0.

Comment: thanks.  'between the read' - which part are you referring to here?

Comment: // For reading user input
            int numberFromUser = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());    XXXX     to        if (numberFromUser == 0){             
  All that (XXXX) does not do anything.  If the number > 0 ; average it. if == 0 exit.